# How to I match a list of word with dictionary items and return the key in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
topic_dic = {

    'Sports': ['play', 'football', 'cricket', 'ball', 'FIFA', 'Basketball', 'Referee', 'Sachin  Tendulkar', 'messi', 'ronaldo', 'EPL', 'manchester united', 'real Madrid', 'juventus', 'contract', 'paul pogba', 'Barcelona', 'transfer'],

    'Politics': ['Barack Obama', 'Donald Trump', 'Prime Minister', 'PM', 'President', 'BJP', 'Amit Shah', 'Lok Sabha', 'Election', 'Modi', 'Government', 'Supreme Court', 'SC', 'India', 'USA', 'Offical', 'Court', 'Legal', 'Judgement'],

    'Science': ['NASA', 'Space', 'James Webb Space', 'Telescope', 'Alien', 'Dawn', 'Mission', 'Galaxy', 'Habitat', 'Magnet', 'Wave', 'Thermals', 'Temperature', 'Orbit', 'Neutrons', 'Mass', 'Discovery'],

    'Social Entertainment': ['Music', 'Dance', 'Singing', 'Concert', 'Audio', 'Playback', 'Competition', 'Movie', 'Drama', 'Theatre'],

    'General Topics': ['Celebrity', 'Culture', 'Society', 'Business', 'Development', 'Country']
}

topics = ['real','retirement','moment,','messi','pogba','play']
```

I have created a dictionary containing key as topics and items related to that topic. I have a list containing some words which I want to compare with the dictionary items.

How to I compare every elements of list topic with items in dictionary and return the key where the item is matching with the list element??
Can i store the keys in different array?

Comment: Great Idea! What have you tried?

Comment: @BlackThunder I don't even understand the question haha.

Comment: @U9-Forward Me too. Forget the `Great Idea`. Its just a joke.

Comment: @BlackThunder Lol, hahahaha., yeah

Comment: HaHa this one I get but I agree some questions are harder to read than code @u9-forward

Comment: @vash_the_stampede Lol, yeah, after first answer by  blhsing i kind oof got the question but i think why bother answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

```
new_array ={}

for i in topics:
    for k in topic_dic:
        if i in str(topic_dic[k]):
            print(f"{i} located in {k}")  
            if k not in new_array:
                new_array[k] = [i] 
            elif k in new_array:
                [v.append(i) for v in new_array.values()]

print(new_array)
```

Updated solution to include creating a new dictionary with found `key` and `value`'s, not sure if this is what you meant by storing `key` in new array.  If you could be more specific with an output format you would like, that would help.

**Output**

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/AtBS$ python3.7 loop_info.py 
> real located in Sports
> messi located in Sports
> pogba located in Sports
> play located in Sports
> {'Sports': ['real', 'messi', 'pogba', 'play']}
> ```

Here's a easier to read format of your dictionary as well

```
topic_dic = {
    'Sports': [
        'play','football','cricket','ball','FIFA','Basketball','Referee',
        'Sachin  Tendulkar','messi','ronaldo','EPL','manchester united',
        'real Madrid','juventus','contract','paul pogba','Barcelona','transfer'
    ],
    'Politics': [
        'Barack Obama','Donald Trump','Prime Minister','PM', 'President',
        'BJP','Amit Shah','Lok Sabha','Election','Modi','Government',
        'Supreme Court','SC','India','USA','Offical','Court','Legal',
        'Judgement'
    ],
    'Science': [
        'NASA','Space','James Webb Space','Telescope','Alien','Dawn',
        'Mission','Galaxy','Habitat','Magnet','Wave','Thermals','Temperature',
        'Orbit','Neutrons','Mass','Discovery'
    ],
    'Social Entertainment': [
        'Music','Dance','Singing','Concert','Audio','Playback',
        'Competition','Movie','Drama','Theatre'
    ],
    'General Topics': [
        'Celebrity','Culture','Society','Business','Development','Country'
    ]
}

topics = ['real','retirement','moment,','messi','pogba','play']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following dict comprehension to build a mapping of the words in `topics` to their respective categories:

```
print({w: k for k, l in topic_dic.items() for t in l for w in topics if w in t})
```

This returns:

```
{'play': 'Sports', 'messi': 'Sports', 'real': 'Sports', 'pogba': 'Sports'}
```